# ssh-keygen -f option, with PowerShell, continues to say folder not exists despite it does

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, home-folder, ssh-keygen

I'm using the PowerShell terminal in Windows 10.
I created a folder "new_folder" in ~/.ssh

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/new_folder
```

Then I try to run `ssh-keygen` with the `-f` option.
The documentation says `"[-f output_keyfile]"`.
Both `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/new_folder`
and `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/new_folder/new_file` fail with this error:

```
Saving key "~/.ssh/new_folder" failed: No such file or directory
```

I did the same using CMD terminal, and it works with both relative and
absolute path.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f "C:/Users/alex/.ssh/new_key"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f "./new_key"
```

What's wrong with `ssh-keygen` in **PowerShell** ?

Comment: (1) The text does not correspond the picture (`new_folder` vs `new`). (2) It *seems* the tilde is not expanded in the `ssh-keygen` case. I know little about Windows, nothing about PowerShell, so this is not an answer.

Comment: The two commands are not even the same…

Comment: Thanks. I removed the images (just there to show the error).  PS and CMD commands are slightly different because the nature of their console... CMD does not have the tilde for user home path. Also adjusted the order of parameters (not sure if that was relevant) to be the same.

Comment: Is the "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" system service running? Try also to use `c:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh\id_rsa`. Avoid using the tilde. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Yes, as Kamil pointed out (I missed his initial comment) the tilde is not working (expanded). That was actually the right answer.  
 I assumed it was fine because _mkdir_ accepts it. 
So, yes, using C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh\my_key works fine.  
(@harrymc,  no "OpenSSH Authentication Agent" is not running, it is disabled!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde in PowerShell only works under certain conditions,
so it's better to avoid it, because you can't know without trying
if it will work in your context.

So, instead of  `~/.ssh/` you should use `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh`.
This will work in all cases.

Comment: instead of `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` just use `"$HOME\.ssh"`

Comment: You can also use `(Resolve-Path '~').Path` which should resolve to `C:\Users\USERNAME` (or whatever your `$HOME` value is).